# Android Remote Video with Titanium

Tags: android, video, titanium

Greetings all!

I'm trying to play a video that is hosted on our webserver on an android phone. I've already built this for iPhone and it works great.

Droid, however is a different issue. Instead of getting video, I'm just getting a black screen, no error or anything.

The code I am using is:

activeContent = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
      contentURL: content,
      backgroundColor:'#111',
      movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT
});

win.add(activeContent);
activeContent.play();

The video I'm downloading does play on the droid when not using Titanium, so I know its not a format issue. (its an .MP4 incase anyone is wondering.)

I've used Titanium SDK's 1.5.1 and am on the continuous build of 1.6.0 from earlier today.

using the 2.2 Droid SDK, and Titanium Developer 1.2.2

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? One of the big selling points for android is its ability to pull media from the net, and I'm honestly a little concerned about this shortcoming if its an issue with Titanium.

Answer (score 2):

For Android, the video player should not be added to the window. Android will open its video player in a new window when you call play(). So your code should instead look like this:

activeContent = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({ contentURL: content, backgroundColor:'#111', movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT });

activeContent.play();

Blessings!

Answer (score 0):

In 1.6.1 kitchen sink Android is able to play a local video, but not remote videos.  I've gotten my video playing to work in iPhone but not in Android.